# Javascript. Why won't my string replace update show in my browser

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the word "lion" to "monkey" by using a function by using .replace in Javascript. I have set a time interval on it and it does work, but only in the console. Not in the browser when I am viewing the page. Why? Do I need to assign/update/upload it to the HTML somehow?

```js
function toggleCaps(){  
let text = document.querySelector(".about").innerText;
console.log(text);
  
var sum = text.replace(/lion/g, "monkey");

console.log(sum);

  
}
setInterval(toggleCaps, 3000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="about">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>
                       lion
                    </p>
       
                </blockquote>
            </div>
       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're storing the result in `sum`, but you're not setting any value of `sum` back to the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the `html` element with the replaced string as following:

```
function toggleCaps(){  
      let text = document.querySelector(".about").innerText;
      console.log(text);
      var sum = text.replace(/lion/g, "monkey");
      document.querySelector(".about").innerText = sum; //add this
      console.log(sum);
}
setInterval(toggleCaps, 3000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

yes you need to update the html:

```
function toggleCaps(){  
    let text = document.querySelector(".about").innerText;
    console.log(text);

    var sum = text.replace(/lion/g, "monkey");

    console.log(sum);

    document.querySelector(".about").innerText = sum;
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Works perfectly.